# R1703:The if statement can be replaced with 'return bool(test)'

Tags: pytest, pylint

I write a function to check if the file exists, but pylint throws a message:"R1703:The if statement can be replaced with 'return bool(test)". What the message means? In addition, how to write a pytest script to test my code below?

```
def is_file_valid(file):
    """
    check if input file exits
    :param file: file
    :return: True/False
    """
    if os.path.exists(file):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I've tried if ...==1: but it seems not work.

```
def is_file_valid(file):
    """
    check if input file exits
    :param file: file
    :return: True/False
    """
    if os.path.exists(file)==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For pytest script, I write...

```
file_test = 'test.txt'  # actually this file does not exist.
def test_is_file_valid(file_test):
    # test is_file_valid()
    assert os.path.exists(file_test) is False, "No this file"
    os.remove(file_test)
```

pytest only shows the following message:

ERROR test/unit/test_io_utils.py::test_is_file_valid

Do you guys have any ideas how to figure it out?

Comment: You can replace your entire `if..else` block with `return os.path.exists(file) = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion means that your function could be rewritten to return a boolean result without the need for an `if` statement. In your case  `os.path.exists` already returns a boolean so it's as simple as returning its result directly.

```py
def is_file_valid(file):
    """
    check if input file exits
    :param file: file
    :return: True/False
    """
    return os.path.exists(file)
```

However, **whether the function in this state actually makes sense**, is in my opinion questionable because I don't see any "added value" compared to using `os.path.exists(file)` directly.

As for how to test it... create (or not) a file in Pytest's temporary folder:

```py
def test_is_file_valid_true(tmp_path):
    file = tmp_path / 'file.txt'
    file.touch()

    assert is_file_valid(file)

def test_is_file_valid_false(tmp_path):
    file = tmp_path / 'file.txt'

    assert not is_file_valid(file)
```

Comment: I agree, you should use ``os.path.exists(file)`` directly (i.e. also remove ``is_file_valid``) but pylint does not detect it.